# Change this code to send attachment as XLSX

Tags: microsoft-excel, macros, code

I need to change this code to send a certain area as an xlsx attached in outlook and not as a pdf.

```
Sub EnviarEmailPeloExcelAnexoPDF()
    Dim sPara      As String
    Dim sMsg       As String
    Dim sAssunt    As String
    Dim PdfCaminho As String
    Dim PdfNome    As String
    
    '            ALTERE O CAMINHO Q SERA SALVO O PDF SE NECCESS.
    PdfCaminho = VBA.Environ("X_BOASJ") & "C:\Users\boasj\OneDrive - Tate & Lyle\Desktop\"
    '            ALTERE O NOME DO PDF DE ACORDO COM A NECESS.
    PdfNome = "FolhaFrequência" & VBA.Format(VBA.Now, "yyyy-mm-dd") & ".pdf"
    
    ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypeXLSM, Filename:= _
    PdfCaminho & PdfNome, Quality:= _
    xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
    OpenAfterPublish:=False

    sPara = Range("R3").Value
    
    If Not sPara = "" Then
        sAssunt = Range("B9").Value
        sMsg = "Olá," & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Segue em anexo sua folha frequência deste mês, favor preencher e ao final do mês nos retornar com a aprovação de seu gestor."
        Envia_Emails sPara, sMsg, sAssunt, PdfCaminho & PdfNome
    End If
    
End Sub

Sub Envia_Emails(sPara As String, sMsg As String, sAssunt As String, PdfAnexo As String)
    Dim OutlookApp   As Object
    Dim OutlookMail  As Object
    Set OutlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutlookMail = OutlookApp.CreateItem(0)
    
    With OutlookMail
        .To = sPara
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = sAssunt
        .Body = sMsg
        .Attachments.Add PdfAnexo
        .Display ' para envia o email diretamente defina o código  .Send
        
    End With
    Set OutlookMail = Nothing
    Set OutlookApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

First change the file extension in the file name:

```
PdfNome = "FolhaFrequência" & VBA.Format(VBA.Now, "yyyy-mm-dd") & ".xlsx"
```

Then save as instead of export. So:

```
ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypeXLSM, Filename:= _
    PdfCaminho & PdfNome, Quality:= _
    xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
    OpenAfterPublish:=False
```

Becomes:

```
ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.SaveAs FileName:=PdfCaminho & PdfNome, FileFormat:=xlWorkbookDefault
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Eduardo, but actually I need to attach the file as.xlsx in an automatic e-mail instead of PDF. :(

Comment: That's what I did. I just have not renamed the variables, only the file name and type so your code changes less. After changing the code with the one I provided, you can rename the variables.